# CakePHP - refresh select field after modalbox closes

Tags: javascript, cakephp

I'm attempting to refresh a select field (using Form Helper) after a ModalBox window closes (see http://modalbox-cakephp-demo.nerdnotes.org/customers/ for example)

The basic concept will be presenting a user with a select field with categories, if the user wishes to add a new category they can click a link which will present a ModalBox window, once that window closes I need to refresh the above select field.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Nate S.

Answer (score 0):

I retag with javascript because you would need that to have the intended behavior. The general step is: use ajax to send a new category name to your categories/add and get back the newly inserted category id. Use js to add that to the select box.